# Swift alarm clock UIswitch

Tags: xcode, swift, clock, alarm

when creating an alarm clock, is it the right way to directly display all scheduled local notifications on a table view? If so, After the notifications have fired they disappear. How can i stop them from disappearing so i can use switches to set them on and off?
What i understood about UIswitch is that i have to cancel the notification when off then reschedule them when on.

```
@IBAction func addAlarm(sender: UIButton) {
    let notification = UILocalNotification()

    notification.fireDate = timePicker.date.fireDate
    notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    notification.alertBody = "Its time"
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1
    notification.hasAction = true
    notification.alertAction = "View"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
    alarmTable.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array to store the times of the alarms.
Then you can easily show and manage them and create `UILocalNotification`s based on them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the timezone before defining the firedate